# JQuery - text put in the wrong table column using display block

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is not the text put in the right column (td) in case? I have tested that *this only happends when the tr-block is hidden earlier and then shown.*

```
        $('#button_phonenumber').click(function() {

           $('#cmobile_row').css('display', 'block');   
           $('#customer_phonenumber').css('display', 'none');
           $('#cmobile').text($('#cphonenumber').val());

    });
```

**html**

```
        </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>location:</td>
                <td><span id="clocation"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Email:</td>
                <td><span id="cemail"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="cmobile_row">
                <td>phone:</td>
                <td><span id="cmobile"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

**image**

[image]

You see here that the dynamically set phonenumer is not in its suppossed column . Instead it seem to belong to the same column as the text.

What is the cause of this and how could it possibly be solved?

Comment: Where did you place the values of the td's? I don't see <td><span id="cmobile">070-5555555</span></td> for example

Comment: @Gilko - the inputform is not shown here and its hidden when the user submits. The phonenumber is set dynamically and what I wrote first is that everything works just fine IF I not hide and then show the <tr>, via jquery

Comment: Have you tried 'inline-block'?

Comment: @Gilko - thanks, yes - but it did not work .-( But I just found that using **visibility** instead of **display** works - but the bad thing is that function occupyies space in the browser. I am still looking for a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this with `display:table-row` or use `jquery` with `.show()` event.

```js
$('#button_phonenumber').click(function() {
  $('#cmobile_row').css('display', 'table-row'); 
  $('#customer_phonenumber').css('display', 'none');
  $('#cmobile').text($('#cphonenumber').val());
});
$('#button_phonenumbers').click(function() {
  $('#cmobile_row').show(); 
  $('#customer_phonenumber').css('display', 'none');
  $('#cmobile').text($('#cphonenumber').val());
});
```

```css
#cmobile_row{
   display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="button_phonenumber" style="color:red">Click me : With display:table-row</div>
<table>   
  <tr>
    <td>location:</td>
    <td><span id="clocation">Ville</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email:</td>
    <td><span id="cemail">dfsfd@sdfsd.com</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="cmobile_row">
    <td>phone:</td>
    <td><span id="cmobile">078855554</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div id="button_phonenumbers" style="color:red">Click me : With .show()</div>
```